# Installing a Fortran-based R package in MRO shows the copyright message in link line

Tags: r, linux

I am using Microsoft R Open (MRO) 4.0.2 on RHEL8. Trying to install the [minqa package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=minqa). During the build process, there are a bunch of warning messages which I ignore. But in what seems to be the final line, linking the shared library file, it fails because the line looks like this:

```
g++: error: Microsoft: No such file or directory
g++: error: R: No such file or directory
g++: error: Open: No such file or directory
g++: error: 4.0.2: No such file or directory
g++: error: The: No such file or directory
g++: error: enhanced: No such file or directory
g++: error: R: No such file or directory
g++: error: distribution: No such file or directory
...
```

This is the first time I have seen such an error while installing R packages.

I think I have traced it down to the file `src/Makevars` in the minqa source package. It has one line:

```
PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"`
```

and on the command line, the command `Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"` just prints out the copyright statement.

Question is: how to fix this so that the minqa package will build and install correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to comment out (or delete) that line in the `src/Makevars` file:

```
## -*- mode: makefile; -*-

##PKG_LIBS = `$(R_HOME)/bin/Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"`
```

Create a new tarball:

```
tar zcf minqa_1.2.4_new.tar.gz minqa
```

Then build from that modified tarball:

```
R CMD INSTALL minqa_1.2.4_new.tar.gz
```